# Laravel 5 keeps me logged in

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying a simple login form in laravel with Auth class, what I notice is that it keeps me logged in even if I close the browser or restart the computer. I want a login that keeps me logged in only while the tab is open. How can I do that?
The code from the controller:

```
public function doLogin()
{

$rules = array(
'username'    => 'required',
'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be     alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
);

// run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

// if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
if ($validator->fails()) {
return Redirect::to('login')
    ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
    ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input     (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
} else {

// create our user data for the authentication
$userdata = array(
    'username'     => Input::get('username'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password')
);

// attempt to do the login
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

    // validation successful!
    // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
    // return Redirect::to('secure');
    // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
    return Redirect::to('user');

} else {        

    // validation not successful, send back to form 
    echo "username ose pass gabim";

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `config/session.php` set `expire_on_close` to `true`.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Answer (score 0):

change in `config/session.php`

```
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

to

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```